# All rows not visible for other users in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySQL instance set up on my machine and other users are connected to the database set up on my machine.

But whenever they do

```
Select * from table_name;
```

They are not able to see all the rows present in the table, whereas I am able to see.
All of them are able to see same number of rows.

I have granted them all privileges as well by using the following query.

```
grant all ON * . * TO 'username'@'hostname';
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: which tool there are using to execute query and how many rows they all are getting same rows all or different.

Comment: they are using select * query in mysql to see rows and they all are able to see the same number of rows.

Comment: I mean querying by which tool  like sqlyog or or by any other tool.

Comment: select * from mytable limit 1000, 100; please use this query and check if rows are changing.

Comment: Yes. The answer is similar . I have posted. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Got the answer. 
There is an option of toggle number of records limitations in mysql. 
After clicking on that option, now they are able to see the number of rows.